# Reading XML elements content with DOM4J

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dom4j

I need some help.

I have the following `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<simulation>
  <member id="House">
    <id>1</id>
    <agent_name>1</agent_name>
    <type>1</type>
    <max_usage>1</max_usage>
    <min_usage>1</min_usage>
    <average_usage>1</average_usage>
  </member>
  <member id="CSP">
    <id>2</id>
    <agent_name>2</agent_name>
    <type>2</type>
  </member>
  <member id="VPP">
    <id>3</id>
    <agent_name>3</agent_name>
    <type>3</type>
  </member>
</simulation>
```

I'm trying to save the numbers into an `ArrayList<String>` like this: *{1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3}*

However I'm having trouble doing it.

Here's my code:

```
public static void readSimulation(){
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();
        DefaultListModel tempList = new DefaultListModel();
        ArrayList<String> tempAL = new ArrayList();

        for ( Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Element element = (Element) i.next();
            tempList.addElement(element.attributeValue("id")); 
            tempAL.add(element.getData().toString()); //I think this is the line that doesn't work
        }

        pt.ipp.isep.gecad.masgrip.Simulation.setDlm(tempList);
        pt.ipp.isep.gecad.masgrip.Simulation.setComponentsFromXML(tempAL);
}
```

I've tryed to print the content of tempAL and the output is this:

```
[






  , 



  , 



  ]
  [






  , 



  , 



  ]
  [






  , 



  , 



  ]
```

I don't know why, can you please help me to get the expected content from XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating through the children of `simulation` only. In other words, you are only looking at the 3 `member` elements rather than their children.

The empty space stored in your ArrayList is the text (white space, hard returns, etc) that you are using to nicely format the child nodes of the `member` elements.

You can complete your parsing by adding another loop within your for loop. Something like this:

```
    for ( Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Element element = (Element) i.next();
        tempList.addElement(element.attributeValue("id")); 

        for ( Iterator j = element.elementIterator(); j.hasNext(); ) {
            Element innerElement = (Element) j.next();
            tempAL.add(innerElement.getData().toString()); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting error in second line of your code("Element element = (Element) i.next();"), it says in convertible type. And also I have typecast ((Iterator)root.elementIterator()), otherwise it gives error. Can you please help me out

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.xml.example;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadXML {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File("sample.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("member");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                System.out.println("----------------------------");
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName() + " : " + nNode.getTextContent());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This example hopefully should help you. It is printing all the values you need but you if you want individual value you can also use below code in for loop.

```
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
    NodeList childNodes = eElement.getChildNodes();
    for (int x = 0 ; x < childNodes.getLength() ; x++) {

    System.out.println(childNodes.item(x).getNodeName() + " : " + childNodes.item(x).getTextContent());
 }                  
}
```